# Get the top x values (independent of the sign) from a list with sign using TCL or sqlite

Tags: list, sqlite, sorting, tcl

Having a list with positive and negative numbers the goal is the ge the top x values based on the abs value of the numbers, but with the sign. e.g.

```
set Input [list -3122.0 -1618.0 -1551.0 -894.2 296.4 2226.0 1855.0 1318.0 872.5 2004.0 2026.0 2828.0 ]
```

Output should be (when requesting only the top 10):

```
Output [ list -3122.0 2828.0 2226.0 2026.0 2004.0 1855.0 -1618.0 -1551.0 1318.0 -894.2 ]
```

I use the following code,

```
set ForceIDsPosetiv [ DB eval {  SELECT Forcec FROM MaxForces WHERE Force > 0} ]
set ForceIDsNegativ [ DB eval {  SELECT Forcec FROM MaxForces WHERE Force < 0} ]
set ForceIDsPosetiv [lsort -decreasing -real $ForceIDsPosetiv]
set ForceIDsNegativ [lsort -increasing -real $ForceIDsNegativ]
set SortedForcList ""

for {set row 0 } { $row <= 9   } {incr row} {
    set firstForcePos [lindex $ForceIDsPosetiv 0]
    set firstForceNeg [lindex $ForceIDsNegativ 0]
    if { $firstForcePos == "" }  {
        lappend SortedForcList $firstForceNeg
        set ForceIDsNegativ [lreplace $ForceIDsNegativ 0 0]
    } else {
        if { $firstForceNeg == "" }  {
            lappend SortedForcList $firstForcePos
            set ForceIDsPosetiv [lreplace $ForceIDsPosetiv 0 0]
        } else {
            if { abs($firstForcePos) > abs($firstForceNeg)  }  {
                lappend SortedForcList $firstForcePos
                set ForceIDsPosetiv [lreplace $ForceIDsPosetiv 0 0]
            } else {
                lappend SortedForcList $firstForceNeg
                set ForceIDsNegativ [lreplace $ForceIDsNegativ 0 0]
            }
        }
    } 
}
```

but I have the feeling that there is a far more efficient way to solve this. Do you have any suggestions? As you can see i use a sqlite db in the beginning. The table has only one column with all the forces. So an solution using sqlite would also be appreciated.

Comment: Is there any specifics for when you have two similar absolute numbers? Like if you have -1 and 1, should one or the other come first? Or does it not matter?

Comment: Order does not matter, but both values shall be kept.

Comment: Added a TCL solution to my answer, fwiw.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know about TCL, but the SQL query would be something like:

```
SELECT Forcec
FROM Maxforces
ORDER BY abs(Forcec) DESC
LIMIT 10
```

The idea is to sort by the absolute values of the numbers in descending order (So the largest one is first), but return the original numbers.

---

Edit: Now I do know about TCL:

```
set Input [list -3122.0 -1618.0 -1551.0 -894.2 296.4 2226.0 1855.0 1318.0 872.5 2004.0 2026.0 2828.0 ]
proc abscomp {a b} {
  set a [::tcl::mathfunc::abs $a]
  set b [::tcl::mathfunc::abs $b]
  if {$a < $b} {
    return -1
  } elseif { $a > $b } {
    return 1
  } else {
    return 0
  }
}
set Output [lrange [lsort -decreasing -command abscomp $Input] 0 9]
```

Comment: Thank you! I did not know about the -command option in lsort...